# 2 Dimensional Array address Book having issues with fgets

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, scanf, fgets

This is my assignment:

Create a program that allows a user to enter up to 10 addresses of friends. Use a two dimensional array to store the address of friends’. After each address is entered, the user should have the option to enter another address or print out a report that shows each addresses entered thus far.

I get most of it but I am having my main issue with fgets.  I keep getting this error:

```
warning: passing arg 1 of `fgets' makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char name[20]= {0};
    char address[40]= {100};
    int choice;
    int i;

    printf("Welcome to the Address Book!\n\n");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)              //start of the array loop. should give an exit    after each entry
    {
        printf("Would you like to (1)Enter an address, or (2)Print the address book?\n");
        scanf("%i",&choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("Please enter a name...\n");
                fgets(name[i],20,stdin);
                printf("You entered %s .", name);
                printf("Please enter an address...\n");
                fgets(address[i],40,stdin);
                printf("You enteres %s .", address);
            }
                break;
            case 2:
                for (i = 0; i<10; i ++)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", name[i]);
                    printf("%s\n", address[i]);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `fgets(name[i],20,stdin);` --> `fgets(name,20,stdin);` or `fgets(name,sizeof name,stdin);` and newline remain of `scanf("%i",&choice);`

Comment: where's your 2d array?

Comment: `char name[20]= {0};` --> `char name[10][20]= {0};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the corrected code in below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    char name[10][20]; //Fix3
    char address[10][40];//Fix4
    int choice;
    int i, j;

    printf("Welcome to the Address Book!\n\n");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)              //start of the array loop. should give an exit    after each entry
    {
        printf("Would you like to (1)Enter an address, or (2)Print the address book?\n");
        scanf("%i",&choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                printf("Please enter a name...\n");
                getchar(); //Fix1
                fgets(name[i],20,stdin); 

                printf("You entered %s .", name);
                printf("Please enter an address...\n");
                //getchar();//Fix2

                fgets(address[i],40,stdin);
                printf("You enteres %s .", address);
            }
                break;
            case 2:
            {
                for (j = 0; j<i; j ++)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", name[j]);
                    printf("%s\n", address[j]);
                }
              }
                break;
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

The corrections are:

1. 2D array is used to get the name and address
2. getchar() is called to consume '\n' before using fgets();

Comment: i would consider some explanation what OP is doing wrong

Comment: You can also delete the initialisers on the arrays, put loop indexes in the loops (unless he's on C89), remove the `getchar()`, reduce the scope of `choice`, remove the extra scopes in the cases, change `printf("%s\n", blah)` into `puts(blah)`, delete the brackets on `return (0)` and I reckon it's perfect after that.

Comment: `scanf("%i\n")`; should be able to remove the `getchar()`

Comment: @HerpDerpington, why scanf("%i\n"); is required ? please explain more on this. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: @HerpDerpington `"%i\n"` : It cause another problem.

Comment: @mahendiran.b @BLUEPIXY hmm yeah, as I said, `scanf` is iffy with the newlines. I take it back, use the `getchar()` to consume the newline.

Comment: Works great and yes Herp it does need some clean up.  So then either getchar() or or scanf() need to be used to know that it will be a keyboard input?  I have looked for hours and hadn't seen that anywhere so thank you very much for your help.  Herp I did try the scanf() in the same context before I posted here and it would compile without errors but then when running it would not give the out put I was looking for.  Something about the buffer... I am new so sorry if I am showing some ignorance.